# How to use strlcpy in g++'s -std=c++0x mode?

Tags: g++, cygwin, string.h

I would like to use `strlcpy` (to call an external api), which is missing from `string.h`, when I use g++'s `-std=c++0x` parameter.

```
% g++ -std=c++0x foo.cpp
foo.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
foo.cpp:5:11: error: 'strlcpy' was not declared in this scope
% g++ foo.cpp
% cat foo.cpp
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  const char src[] = "foo";
  char dest[1024] = { 0 };
  strlcpy(dest, src, sizeof(dest));
  return 0;
}
```

Is it possible to use `strlcpy` and the `std=c++0x` flag, or do I have to drop the later?

Additionally I was not able to find the `strlcpy` manpage in cygwin, even though they seem to have the function. Any pointers?

I use gcc 4.7.2 on cygwin.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting wikipedia: [Criticism on strlcpy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_string_handling#Criticism)

> The more popular strlcat and strlcpy have been criticised on the basis
>   that they encourage use of C strings and thus create more problems
>   than they solve. Consequently they have not been included in the
>   GNU C library (used by software on Linux), although they are
>   implemented in OpenBSD, FreeBSD, NetBSD, Solaris, Mac OS X, QNX, and
>   even internally in the Linux kernel.

Comment: Since the only alternative to not not using c string in my case is to drop the external api, I would rather use the "safer" c strings function, don't you agree?

Comment: Indeed. Just be careful with sizes